# Why is electricity transferred at high voltage

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, loss

I know higher voltage is used because of these two formulas:

**P = V x I**

**P = I^2 x R**

But if we substitute I = V / R in the first formula we get

**P = V^2 / R**

Shouldn’t this mean increasing the voltage will also increase the power loss by an exponent of two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The \$I\$ in \$P=I^2R\$ is referring to current in both the load and the wiring (which is the same, since everything's in series), and the \$R\$ refers to cable resistance. Thus this is a measure of power lost in the cabling.

By contrast, \$V\$ in \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$ is ambiguous. Does it refer to the voltage dropped along the cables, or the voltage across the load, or the total voltage of the supply? If you want a measure of power lost in the cables, then \$R\$ is referring to cable resistance, and \$V\$ must be the voltage dropped along the cables, ***not the supply voltage***.

Assuming we deliver the same \$P=IV\$ power to the load in all cases, then if supply voltage increases, supply current must decrease. If current decreases, the voltage \$V=IR\$ dropped along the cables must also decrease, by Ohm's law.

This simple answer is that you used the wrong \$V\$. In this context, the \$V\$ that you use in the formula \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$ must be the voltage dropped in the cabling.

---

#### Response to comment

Here's a model where \$R_C\$ is cable resistance, consisting of two lengths of cable of resistance \$R_{C1}\$ and \$R_{C2}\$, so total cable resistance is \$R_C = R_{C1}+R_{C2}\$. The load is \$R_L\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feWOTU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_{C1}\$ and \$R_{C2}\$ each have \$V=IR=2.16A\times 1\Omega=2.16V\$ across them (as shown on volmeters VM1 and VM2) for a total of 4.32V. The load only ever sees the remaining \$220V - 4.32V=216V\$, but this isn't important in the context of the question. What's important is the 4.32V "lost" along the cabling.

It is *this* 4.32V that I refer to, which should appear in \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$, along with total cable resistance of 2Ω, and it should not be confused with the 220V source, or the 216V that makes it to the load.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'voltage dropped along the cable'?

Comment: @ACRafi see my update.

Comment: Are these I^2 x R and V^2 / R(where V is the voltage dropped along the circuit) then equal?

Comment: @ACRafi If you measured the voltage across any resistor, and calculated \$\frac{V^2}{R}\$, or measured the current through that same resistor and calculated \$I^2R\$, the two would yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

No, or yes, depending on what voltage you mean.

If you mean the voltage drop of the wire, then yes. Otherwise, no.

If you have 1A going in wire, and have 1V loss in the wire, that's 1W lost in the wire.

That's pretty bad if you are transmitting 2V 1A (2W) into load as only 1V 1A (1W) is received by load as 1W is lost in the wire.

Now if you are trying to trasmit 100V 1A (100W) through same wires to load, the same wiring will have same 1V drop at 1A (1W) and the load gets 99V 1A (99W). Now with higher voltage, the drop in the wire is not very significant.

And using high voltage distribution, you can transfer 400kW at 400kV and 1A, so 1V or 1W drop over wires is almost nothing.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by the voltage drop of the wire?

Comment: @ACRafi Wires are not ideal superconductors. Wires are just resistances and you get voltage drop over resistances when current flows through the resistance.

Comment: Here in the first case the voltage is 2 V and current is 1 A so the resistance of the circuit (load+cable) is 2 ohm. But in the second case you get 100 V, 1 A so how did the circuit resistance increase to 100 ohm?

Comment: @SujalMotagi This isn't about resistance of load but power transmitted to load while 1W is lost in the wire. Feel free to assume AC transformer or DC/DC converter.

Comment: @Justme but how are we even able to get 100 V, 1 A in the first place?

Comment: @SujalMotagi Like I said, that isn't the point, but with a 100V source supply voltage and a 1A load. If you have questions, ask a new question.

Comment: @Justme I'm sorry but this was the point of confusion for me. If we step up the voltage, while keeping the resistance of the circuit the same then the current would also increase.

Comment: @SujalMotagi We are not keeping resistance of the load same. We are explaining how higher voltage allows to deliver more power to loads over same wire resistance with equal power loss in the wire resistance.

Comment: @Justme if we deliver more power to the load we would be increasing the current through it so wouldn't that also increase the power lost in the cable?

Comment: @SujalMotagi No because if cable has 1 ohm resistance, 1A through cable will drop 1V, regardless of if there is 10V going into cable and 9V coming out, or 1000V going into cable and 999V coming out. We are not increasing the current to load. This is not a discussion forum, if you have a question, ask a new question about it.